# Can I install the "scraperwiki" library locally?

Tags: python, scraperwiki

Is the `scraperwiki` python module available for install outside of the Scraperwiki.com web interface? It looks like the [source](https://bitbucket.org/ScraperWiki/scraperwiki/src/efd21ea1c875/scraperlibs/scraperwiki/) is available, but not packaged.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We now have a locally installable version https://github.com/scraperwiki/scraperwiki-python that can be [pip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_%28package_manager%29) installed using `pip install scraperwiki`

Comment: yep, this is now available in github:

https://github.com/scraperwiki/scraperwiki_local

Comment: Seems that the repo was deleted, mind updating it to the correct one?

Comment: [github.com/scraperwiki/scraperwiki-python](https://github.com/scraperwiki/scraperwiki-python)